# Proposal: minimum lifetime for questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

Just putting this out there, I don't really care that much one way or another (though I *used* to care quite a bit in the early days).

As per [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310546/new-questions-getting-deleted-while-im-answering-them) on meta (among others, no doubt), some people have an issue with spending quite a bit of time answering a question only to find that the questioner had closed or deleted it (or possibly that it had been closed/deleted by community voting<sup>(a)</sup>).

I know this used to grate on me quite a bit but I was wondering whether there is an easy solution. That solution is to set a minimum lifetime for questions, during which they cannot be closed/deleted.

I don't mean *preventing* it so much as having it be a 'soft' operation. In other words, let's say user `Newbie` asks a question at 9am and `Unstable` starts answering it immediately with a long, well thought out, detailed 20-minute response.

In the current setting, `Newbie` deleting the question at 9:15 is likely to turn `Unstable` into `RavingLoony`. If the deletion operation from `Newbie` was in fact a soft one, it would mark the question for deletion in (say) an hour, meaning answers in flight would probably still be able to add to the knowledge of SO.

Now, for deletion, the effect on SO itself may not change (unless the question is undeleted) but it may just placate those who feel as if their effort is being wasted. In any case, a question with decent answers can be useful even if closed.

Comment: Closing is *dramatically* more effective the quicker it's done.  The longer you delay closing the question, the less effective it is at accomplishing some of its goals.  The same is also true of deletion, although to a lesser extent.

Comment: I think the number of panicked new users confused as to why they can't delete their question would outnumber the users upset that a question was deleted before they could post their answer. I'm also not sure if their answer existing for 45 minutes before getting deleted anyway would actually placate the users posting answers.

Comment: Okay, so I guess based on the current +2/-21 vote counts, the majority consider this a *bad* idea? Lucky I have thick skin :-) What's the accepted approach here? Delete the question because it's considered a bad idea, or leave it here to make sure no-one else raises it? I know voting here is more to do with agreement/disagreement than the question quality, so I don't want to delete it if it still serves a purpose.

Comment: I recommend maybe adding in the help a way to avoid these problems -- like don't spend 20 minutes writing a post. Write one in like 30 seconds, as fast as you can -- it might be a bad answer and get some downvotes but this way you know you'll get it in there. Same kind of thing with coding -- don't write 4,000 lines of code before you even try to compile it. Then iterate and iterate over it, editing the answer until it gets good (and also stealing bits and pieces of other people's answers). :-D This is the pro way to do it, I think.

Comment: Another thing I think people can do is edit the question first before answering it. If it looks like it might be borderline off-topic or too broad, change it before answering it. We can also, at that point, change the question slightly in a way that asks something which caters to our specific field of expertise, and that way, without changing the author's intentions too much, provide an even better answer than we normally could if we didn't edit the question first. At least this seems like an effective strategy -- lately been thinking about how to get points in a more strategic way.

Answer (score 4):

Someone with enough system experience to legitimately take advantage of this (rather than simply squeezing in Yet Another FGitW) can be quietly informed that there is already a [4-hour server-side grace period during which a suitable userscript or client-side HTML hackery will allow submitting an answer to a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38228/incorrectly-able-to-answer-a-closed-question/44634#44634).

The vast majority of possible answerers, though, are explicitly the ones we **don't want** to answer the question… which is in fact the entire reason for closing it in the first place. Making the effect of closing blunter once it finally goes through, when closing is so endlessly backlogged already, does not seem to be at all sensible.

Questions that can have useful answers added should be *reopened*, not have another systemic hole opened for low-quality answers to be poured through.

I posted a [similar response on the mother meta not long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268312/prevent-questions-put-on-hold-in-the-first-24-48-hours/268315#268315); the question was eventually marked as a dupe of a similar feature request, which might also be of interest.

Comment: FGitW? Something to do with Git?

Comment: [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/274165).

Comment: Ah, silly me, I knew the term, just didn't connect it.